# Hebrew text overflowing cells and causing layout issues in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am experiencing an issue with Hebrew text overflowing cells in Google Sheets. This only happens with Hebrew text, and not with English text. The text overflows and disrupts the layout of the sheet, making it difficult to read and use. The cells themselves become misaligned and distorted, as if there is a bug.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checking cell alignment: The alignment is set to "from right to left", which is the recommended setting for Hebrew text.
- Enabling text wrapping: I have enabled the "Wrap text" option, but the text still overflows.
- Adjusting column width: I have tried widening the columns, but the text still overflows.
- Using a different font: I have tried using different fonts that support Hebrew, but the problem persists.
- Disabling add-ons: I have disabled all add-ons, but the problem still occurs.
- Browser history and cache, I have cleared the browser history and cache, but the issue persists.
- Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings to Israel.

Browser Chrome (Version 121.0.6167.161)

I have attached a screenshot of the issue for your reference.

I would appreciate it if you could investigate this issue and provide a solution.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Screenshot of the issue
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a link to a spreadhseet that exhibits the problem.  You can  use [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to annonymize yourself. More info here: [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/)